# Spree Pagination Product count change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am using spree and make online shopping cart. I want to saw 12 product on per page but right now it show 10 how can I change.

In my spree.rb file i put this code but it cant work

```
Spree::Config.set(:products_per_page => 12)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can change product per page count by using

in spree.rb file insert below code

```
Spree.config do |config|
  config.products_per_page = 100
end
```